# Basics for recursive functions

Tags: functions, matrix, recursion

I am new to Mathematica and try to define a simple recursive formula which is illustrated as below:

```
A[1] := {{0, 0}, {0, 0}} // MatrixForm;
identity := {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
A[n_] := KroneckerProduct[identity, A[n - 1]];
A[2] // MatrixForm
```

The result is expected to be a zero matrix with size 4$\times$4, i.e.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

if I let n=2. However, the returned result is

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
1&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I have checked many times but still don't know what's the error for my code. Could anyone give some hints?

Comment: Don't include display wrappers (e.g., `MatrixForm`) in variable definitions. Use either `MatrixForm[A[1] = ... ]` or `(A[1] = ... )//MatrixForm` to isolate the wrapper from the variable definition.

Comment: In particular, [item number 8 in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/29734).

Answer (score 2):

Notice use of parentheses on line 1 and also on line 4. `MatrixForm` outputs cannot be used in computations.

```
(A[1] := {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}) // MatrixForm;
identity := {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
A[n_] := KroneckerProduct[identity, A[n - 1]];
(A[2]) // MatrixForm
```

\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}